# Array losing a key on the way

Tags: php

Hello i have a piece of code with an example of array and the problem is that i'm loosing a key of the array. The array is a multidimensional one and i have posted here an sample version because i have a lot of keys in it ( too long to post it )

```
$columns = array(
    "1" => array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);
$array = array(
    "1" => array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
),
    "2" => array(
    "1" => "bar",
    "2" => "foo",
    "3" => "bar",
    "4" => "foo",
    "5" => "bar",
    "6" => "foo",
    "7" => "bar",
    "8" => "foo",
    "9" => "bar",
    "10" => "foo",
)
);
```

ok in this two arrays i have a fixed number or keys and what i want to achieve is getting the values from the first array and use them as keys in my second array. So far so good but when i do the second foreach to get the values from first and put them as keys in the second on the way i'm loosing on of my keys from $array ( i think it rewritten ). can you help me out with this code because i have no ideea how to fix it.

```
foreach($array as $key => $val)
{
    array_splice($val, 66);
    foreach($val as $k => $row) 
    {
        if ( isset($columns[$k])) 
        {
            $info[$columns[$k]] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $info;
}
```

Update:

What i wanted to achieve here was creating an array using an array for keys and another one for values. Later on discovered that i can do it with array_combine. Solved my problem

Comment: If you wrote [minimal example](http://sscce.org/) it's more likely that someone could help you. Or even you may understand the error yourself

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't distinguish between 1 and "1" as array keys.

So the following are the same:

```
$array["1"] = $something;
$array[1] = $something;
```

They both assign to the 2nd element in `$array` (possibly overwriting exiting data).

Comment: yes instead of keeping me the two arrays i have in the second array in overwrites the second array in the second array and i'm loosing the first array from the second array ( it's a multidimensional one )

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way of doing this: use the [`array_flip`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) function.

Comment: it would do the job but i don't wanna flip the values with the keys i want to use the values from first array as keys in the second array :D

Comment: So, `array_values`? Your question doesn't explain very well what you're trying to do; you need a better example (like, one that doesn't repeat itself as much).